# Passing an object and files to Web Api 2 Controller from ajax Illegal Invocation

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to pass from Ajax a ViewModel object and some files to an aspnet web api 2 controller but throws out an error with TypeError: Illegal invocation, if i remove the extra files object this works fine.

```
                           $.ajax({
                                url: `/api/issues/${ViewModels.issueViewModel.id}`,
                                method: "PUT",
                                data: {dto: ViewModels.issueViewModel, emailAttach: attachFileData},
                                headers: {
                                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                                }
                            })
```

issueViewModel is a key value pair object and emailAttach will be files attached to a FormData
The webapi2 controller

```
 public IHttpActionResult CreateIssue(IssueDto dto, List<HttpFileCollectionBase> emailAttach)
    {
        //Some logic to handle objects passed
    }
```

The IssueDto looks like this

```
public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }

    public List<int> PersonId { get; set; } //Extra 
    public List<string> ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public List<string> AttachedFiles { get; set; }

    public List<PslApplicationDto> PslApplicationDto { get; set; }
    public UrgencyFlag UrgencyFlag { get; set; }
    public CompletionFlag CompletionFlag { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CompletionDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateIssueRegistered { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdate { get; set; }
    public int CompletionDuration { get; set; }

    public SolutionDto SolutionDto { get; set; }
    public PsUserDto PsUser{ get; set; }
    public EmailDto EmailDto { get; set; }
    public IssueCategorieDto Category { get; set; }
    public List<PersonDto> PersonDtos { get; set; }
    public List<IssueTagsDto> IssueTags { get; set; }
    public List<int> IssueTagsId { get; set; } // Extra info

    public int CategorieId { get; set; }
    public int PsUserId { get; set; }
```

All this information are bound to the ViewModel and passed to the controller
  And emailAttach is a key value FormData generated from thise code

```
function attachFile(e) {
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
e.preventDefault();

var attachmentInput = document.getElementById("attachInput");

if (typeof (attachmentInput.files[0]) === "undefined") {
    return toastr.error("Please select a file to attach");
}


attachFileData.append(attachmentInput.files[0].name, attachmentInput.files[0]);
appendAttachmentToForm(attachmentInput.files[0]);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the data type of dto and files in the IssueDto class to string.

Comment: Am sorry mabye i did not explained this well IssueDto doesn't contain dto as an object dto maps to IssueDto and files shouldnt be mapped with dto they should be just passed to the controller to access via the Request.

Comment: Yes... when they are passed to a controller there must be a class named IssueDto.. In the object of this class the passed value will be stored.

Comment: Hi Sorry i realised what you were saying but there is a reasson i cant change everything to a string and am not really sure if i understand what you mean but i've updated the code to clearly explain what i mean